# Multiple graphs in one diagram python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, subplot

I know that we could use subplots for simple line graphs etc. in Python to show multiple graphs next to each other. I nevertheless have the issue that I need to group different graph types.

Currently, my graph is the following:

[image]

My issue is that I want to group three plots of the same type next to each other.

Target Graph
[image]

My code in Python:

```
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

df = {
    'Bins': [1,2,3,4],
    '2017-2019': [0.3, 0.42, 0.48, 0.55],
    '2020-2021': [0.25, 0.44, 0.5, 0.35]    
}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

left_label = [str(c) + ', '+ str(round(y)) for c, y in zip(df.Bins, df['2017-2019'])]
right_label = [str(c) + ', '+ str(round(y)) for c, y in zip(df.Bins, df['2020-2021'])]
klass = ['red' if (y1-y2) < 0 else 'green' for y1, y2 in zip(df['2017-2019'], df['2020-2021'])]

# draw line
def newline(p1, p2, color='black'):
    ax = plt.gca()
    l = mlines.Line2D([p1[0],p2[0]], [p1[1],p2[1]], color='red' if p1[1]-p2[1] > 0 else 'green', marker='o', markersize=4)
    ax.add_line(l)
    return l

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(12,8), dpi= 80)

# Vertical Lines
ax.vlines(x=0.5, ymin=0.2, ymax=0.6, color='black', alpha=0.7, linewidth=1, linestyles='dotted')
ax.vlines(x=1.5, ymin=0.2, ymax=0.6, color='black', alpha=0.7, linewidth=1, linestyles='dotted')

# Line Segment sand Annotation
for p1, p2, c in zip(df['2017-2019'], df['2020-2021'], df['Bins']):
    newline([0.5,p1], [1.5,p2])
    ax.text(0.5-0.05, p1, c, horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='center', fontdict={'size':12}) 
    ax.text(1.5+0.05, p2, c, horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='center', fontdict={'size':12})

# Decoration
ax.set_title("XXX", fontdict={'size':12}, x = 0.35)
ax.set(xlim=(0,3), ylim=(0.2,0.6))
ax.set_xticks([0.5,1.5])
ax.set_xticklabels(["2017-2019", "2020-2021"], fontsize = 10, weight = 700)

plt.gca().set_yticklabels(['{:.0f}%'.format(x*100) for x in plt.gca().get_yticks()]) 

#ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

# Lighten borders
plt.gca().spines["top"].set_alpha(.0)
plt.gca().spines["bottom"].set_alpha(.0)
plt.gca().spines["right"].set_alpha(.0)
plt.gca().spines["left"].set_alpha(.25)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't know what your actual question is but it seems you should read [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html).

Comment: "I want to group three plots of the same type as shown below next to each other": so... subplots?

Comment: Reading your question, it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have updated my question - thank you all for your tips!